# How do I add online database to game in Unity?

Tags: c#, sql, database, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I was wondering what was the best way to go about implementing an online database for my game. It only has to store player scores and player names.

The game is for Windows build. Are there any useful tools for setting up an online database for windows games?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need to figure out what Database you want to use. I recommend you to use a classic SQL based Database like MySQL or MariaDB. After that you only need to search for a .Net/C# Driver/Library for the Database Engine you have chosen and use that in your Unity Project or just use the SqlClient namespace that comes with .Net

This will get you started without third party dependencies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you set up a cloud service such as Azure for the DB and connect to it using RESTful microservices where you implement the desired actions like GET scores, PUT score, etc.

EDIT: Here is a simpler suggestion, use the official Microsoft SDK to connect to a CosmosDB (noSQL) and store/retrieve the data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/gamedev/unity/azure-storage-unity